# Anyway to calculate surface area affected by lights?

Tags: light

was wondering if there is any way to calculate the surface area directly affected by a light source. For example, when a light source is added inside a small house model, would it be possible to extract the surfaces that are bright?

If this can be done, is it possible to control the light intensity or extract out the shadowed surface as well?

Thank you,

Comment: I think it should be possible to tie a transparency node to a Light Path node in the materials, so the more lit something is, the more opaque it becomes. Maybe try experimenting with that?